# Query SQL condition show all data in table 1 and table 2

Tags: mysql

I create 2 tables:

**table 1:
student**

- id_student varchar5
- student_name varchar[30]

**table 2:
absent**

- id_absent int[11] (pk)
- id_student varchar[5] (fk)
- date_absent [date]
- info_absent varchar[15]

I want show absent this today, but I want show all data student.

Example

```
**name | info_absent**

ridwan | present

adesta | present

eko  | null 

desti | null
```

This data sample absent this today maybe eko or desti not present or sick.

When I query like this :

```
SELECT sw.student_name,ab.info_absent
    FROM student AS sw 
    left outer join absent AS ab  on
    sw.id_student=ab.id_student
     where ab.date_absent='now()'
```

This only show data

```
**name | info_absent**

ridwan | present

adesta | present
```

I want eko and desti also show in this data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Is this working as you want?

```
SELECT sw.student_name, ab.info_absent FROM student sw 
LEFT JOIN absent ab ON ab.id_student = sw.id_student && ab.date_absent = NOW();
```

You can also replace NULL in info_absent for whatever you want like this:

```
SELECT sw.student_name, IFNULL(ab.info_absent, 'Seems present') FROM student sw 
LEFT JOIN absent ab ON ab.id_student = sw.id_student && ab.date_absent = NOW();
```

Comment: Practicly only change is, you had to add date_absent check to ON, instead of WHERE, because you want to check it on joined rows, not on already joined tables. Other changes were only cosmetic, except one - you can't have now() in quotes, because it's function. You was comparing it to string 'now()' instead of current date.

Answer (score -1):

Why not just

```
SELECT sw.student_name,ab.info_absent
FROM student AS sw 
left outer join absent AS ab  on
sw.id_student=ab.id_student
```

Comment: hey, check my question i want show all data students and absent 
today.  not all date in my database.